# What would this Sorcery Fix do for Exalted?

Tags: exalted

So we have an exalted group that has a pair of melee people buzzsawing through things with Peony Blossom attack, another with the flamethrower martial art, the talker, and a wizard. The sorceror is a lunar and is absolutely obsessed with doing fire attacks in response to everything, but due to the charge up time nature of spells, the player is upset that they only really get one turn. I have proposed firing from very far away, but the player doesn't see that as satisfactory so I was thinking up the following fix.

If the spell in question does not have a time listed for casting (it follows the normal shaping sorcery rules), then dial everything back by one step. 1st circle can be used as a speed 5 action. 2nd circle requires a shape sorcery action and 3rd circle requires two.

How would this affect a game's balance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The sorceror is a lunar and is absolutely obsessed with doing fire attacks in response to everything, but due to the charge up time nature of spells, the player is upset that they only really get one turn.

This stood out to me. This player sounds like he's operating outside established theme of Lunars: adaptable, practical, capricious. Aside from being lazy, this strategy ignores what Lunars are about.

In a system like Exalted, I recommend talking to your player about exploring other options to be combat-ready. Emphasize Charms over Sorcery. This character is based around fire: what about fire is so appealing? Look into other resources to support the character such as special equipment or martial arts.

To answer your original question, speeding things up like this is likely to shift a lot of power to this character, which will force the ST to compensate with more hardy opponents. Does this character have something else to do when motes or wp are spent?

Comment: I will admit that the player IS acting outside of Lunar themes. After reviewing some of the past games the plaeyr was involved in, I come to realize that her MO is always the same. "Jerk standoffish loner who HAS to have fire based attacks". She has yet to even claim any hearts blood so I wonder if she should have gone fire aspect Dragonblood with the lore bolt charms.